# jQuery match div height with dynamic image height

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, css

I have a image which has a width set to 100% and a min-width of 1024px. I want to keep my 'shadow' div over the image, and also match it's height as the window size changes, which causes the image size to proportionately change to the window width. My current code appears to do nothing...

Template is here http://jordan.rave5.com/tmp/ you'll notice the backgroudn-overlay and background-gradient divs don't expand 100% of the document. That's another problem. Lol. I'm trying to get them to be the BG 100% width and height.

**jQuery:**

```
            $('.header-img').css('height', function(imgheight) {
                $('.image-grad').css({'height': + imgheight});
            });
```

**CSS:**

```
            .image-grad {
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 600;
                transition: width 2s;
                -webkit-transition: width 2s;
                width: 100%;
                min-height: 174px;
                max-height: 608px;
                background-image: url(images/header-img.png);
                background-repeat: repeat-x;
                background-position: bottom;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
            }

            .header-img {
                position: relative;
                z-index: 500;
                width: 100%;
                min-width: 1024px;
                opacity: 0.0;
            }
```

**HTML:**

```
                    <img class="header-img" src="slides/fields.jpg" alt="Panoramic Fields" />
                    <div class="image-grad"></div>
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: can you create a fiddle out of your question? it will be easier that way

Comment: yup create a fiddle and i will be easier

Comment: It's hard to create a fiddle as it doesn't work correctly (no resizing of the window for the boxes) I can just upload the template to a host

Comment: http://jordan.rave5.com/tmp/ Here is the template. Don't laugh... I haven't done any web development since 04-05 in any sort of serious application, so I'm relearning from a few books I picked up about HTML5 and CSS/CSS3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to set the height of the div using `.height`

you can do something like the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q4DRp/

```
var imageGrad = $('.image-grad'),
    image = $('.header-img');

function resizeDiv () {
    imageGrad.height(image.height());
    imageGrad.width(image.width());
}

resizeDiv();

$(window).resize(function() { resizeDiv(); });
```

Comment: Is there a way to set the height to 324 in the initial load? It appears that the image height it gets when it first loads is the actual image height, and not the stretched version.

Comment: @WASasquatch run the `resizeDiv` function on `window.onload` instead of `document.ready`, otherwise you can set the height by using `imageGrad.height(324)`

Comment: Thanks bud, much appreciated. If you know what's up with my fixed background now being scrollable that'd be a big help too.

Comment: I think it's because your footer has a margin top of 100%;

Answer (score 2):

This will help you resize your shadow image:

**Solution (Not tested)**

```
$('.image-grad').css('height', $('.header-img').attr('height'));
```

To get the height of your image, use .attr('height').
Then to set the height of the div, use .css('height','999').

Comment: I recommend using outerHeight() to get the height (adds padding but not margin) and set the new element with .height() -- I'd write a full answer but super busy today.